# How understand this error? "unsupported destination, should be slice or struct"

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have structure like this:

```
type Users struct{
  ID uint 
  Profile  *Profile
  Name string 
  ProfileID uint 
}
type Profile struct{
  ID uint 
  Name string 
}
```

And I want insert into `User.Profile1 related profile

```
 db.First(&user.Profile, user.ProfileID)
```

Here I get error like this

```
unsupported destination, should be slice or struct
```

And I don't understand why this error appears. I know that solution is create slice of Profile, but I need only one Profile.

Comment: Try `db.First(user.Profile, user.ProfileID)` (without the `&`).

Comment: it doesn't change anything. I've already try it. Thanks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not initialized the Profile struct. You must first initialize the struct.

```
user.Profile = &Profile{}
db.First(user.Profile, user.ProfileID)
```

Comment: There's probably no need for the second `&`, right? `user.Profile` is already a pointer, doing `&user.Profile` would result in a value of type `**Profile` which may, or may not be supported by gorm.

Comment: But you still need to initialize the structure. Otherwise you pass nil

Comment: Wow!  I know this answer but, I want to optimize this code.  Any other solutions ?

Comment: A thought on optimizing: you're making the type in this struct a pointer so it starts as <nil> and then you're generating a spot in memory for an empty struct to pass it along. The user.Profile will already be initialized as the empty struct if you change its type to not be a pointer. Unless you sometimes need the User.Profile to be nil, this seems like a very roundabout way to hold a bunch of empty values and their memory address and on top of that, it won't be safe to use in your go routines.